# CAN bus termination in a fully modular design

Tags: can

I am trying to make a fully modular festo cube design that is controlled with a CAN bus, but I am trying to figure out where to terminate the bus.
I am even not really sure if what I am trying to do is even possible with a CAN bus.
The wiring looks something like this:

[[image: 1]

In every box is a node that is connected to the CAN bus, but there are several open ends in every box were I could connect a termination resistor to. The box on the bottom left is the master box which has a controller connected to it which you could see as the start of the bus. My quess is that I need to connect a termination resistor to every lose end of the bus.

Hope you can help :)

Comment: No this doesn't make much sense. An ideal CAN bus should be one long line. Small stubs are tolerated, but you can't just wildly connect everything to everything.

Comment: Having loops in the CAN bus sounds like a recipe for disaster, to me. CAN isn't designed to work in situations like this at all.

Comment: You can use a star hub and wire every node individually, or daisy chain off one cable, this won't work,

Comment: Although you could find ways to make this work (by stepping way outside of the standard and perhaps doing some modeling and detailed analysis), why would you want to do this? Why not a single serpentine line, or even three separate short stubs? What purpose does this mesh serve?

Comment: @EgarBrown Because I want it to be fully modular,I am trying to make something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c-c1l9r6kLw&t=49s. The point of this wiring is that i can take a cube and put it wherever i want. This means that there will be a lot of lose ends and circles. But if you know a better way of communication, please say so.

Answer (score 6):

The CAN bus is designed for a single line with nodes connected at intervals along it. In this standard layout it is quite obvious that you need to terminate each end of the line to prevent transmission line effects (reflections) at those ends.

In your layout this is not possible as there is no single line. Indeed, your layout will have some serious problems with reflections, not just at each unterminated end stub, but at junctions where multiple lines join. However, all is not lost. If the longest dimension of your bus is roughly 1/10 of the wavelength at the bitrate, then transmission line effects can be disregarded (basically the wave travelling time is much less than the bit time, so by the time you sample the signal value any transmission line effects will have died out). In this situation you can just bulk terminate the bus at the master node to ensure that the bus has sufficient load for the CAN drivers.

However, this means that the maximum bit rate you can run is limited by the length of your network, so you'll have to check this carefully. You might want to reduce the driver slew rate as well to clean up the edges of the signal, particularly if you are not running crystals in each node.

**Edit:** BTW Low-Speed and single wire CAN are designed for exactly this sort of flexible bus structure, so there is nothing inherently wrong with using CAN like this. The answer I provided above outlines how you can use standard CAN in this configuration as low speed CAN transceivers are harder to get now.

Answer (score 6):

It's baffling why you would consider such an arrangement over the tried and tested methods such as this: -

[image]

One cable terminated once at each end minimizes reflections and allows a much higher data rates with minimal errors. It also uses less cable.

Comment: I think their reasoning is that this is a modular design, so they can't be sure all of the blocks will be present. That said, CAN is not suited for things like that, and I doubt any common bus network would work well for it without some form of active routing.

Comment: I can't be sure that all the blocks will be present and that they are in the same location at all time. And I know that CAN isn't really designed for this kind of use but for me it is easy to implement. But if you can think of a better communication protocol for my kind of situations, please say so.

Comment: Comms protocol has nothing to do with the physical implementation of wires.

Comment: @EdwinPap.  You can have a modular design:  The master module has a socket (only), subsidiary modules have a socket + a cable with a plug that fits into the preceding module, and there is a termination plug that goes into the last socket in the chain.  You can then plug them all together like Lego.

Answer (score 1):

For a fully modular design, you may consider using termination that can be switched open or closed at each node.

The next hurdle would be how each node decides if it needs to close/activate termination. This could be done manually via a toggle switch or jumper. For a more automatic solution, they could all be open by default, and decide with some sort of communication protocol that isn't the CAN bus itself.